# Anylogic: Make a source generate 3 different agents

Tags: anylogic, agent

I'm trying to make my source generate 3 different agents (3 different products basically - ProductA, ProductB, ProductC) based on a value read on an Excel file.
How can I make the source generate 3 different types of Agents using the inject() function?

I tried several code combinations (inside or outside the source) but none is working.

Thank you in advance,
Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and **should not**. Use 3 `Source` blocks instead, each creating a different type.

You can easily send them into the same downstream flow chart blocks, if you like.

Comment: However, you can change your definition of `Product`: just have 1 `Product` agent type and inside it, have a flag parameter `p_ProductType` that distinguishes the individuals. Which approach is better? It depends :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How can i create a flag parameters to identify my products lets say inside a queue?

And if I use 3 different source blocks, then can I use the same exit-enter block all different kind of agents?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you are supposed to do, but I will tell you anyways just for fun

At the end of the source block you have the option to make a source as a population of sources:
[image: source population]
You will create 3 as the population number since you have 3 products.

With that done, you can inject to the source based on an index... where each index corresponds to a product:

```
source.get(index).inject();
```

Finally in the agent section you will click on the equal sign
[image]

and write this code:

```
index==0 ? 
new ProductA() : 
index==1 ? 
new ProductB()
: 
new ProductC()
```

Comment: thx Felipe. Good answer for future users, but as you said: One should typically not use this approach. But ... one can :D